# grpc-gateway : cannot find package "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-gateway

I am trying to setup grpc gateway. Have tried all the steps mentioned at Github.
The reverse proxy file is getting generated with the following **"github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"**. But when I do go build it is giving me this error  **cannot find package "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"**

Current go verson: go version go1.13.15 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 0):

To use gRPC-Gateway in a `GOPATH` project, you will need to stick to the `v1` releases. If you use vendor, you can pin to https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/releases/tag/v1.15.1. Make sure your generator and runtime dependency is using the same version. You can download the generator from the releases page https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/releases.